# Using Selenium on Python to operate Tor. Doesn't work for unknown reasons

Tags: python, selenium, tor

From this website
http://www.thedurkweb.com/automated-anonymous-interactions-with-websites-using-python-and-tor/

I did the following code

```
enter code here

import stem.process
from stem import Signal
from stem.control import Controller
from splinter import Browser

proxyIP = "127.0.0.1"
proxyPort = 9150

proxy_settings = {"network.proxy.type": 1,
              "network.proxy.ssl": proxyIP,
              "network.proxy.ssl_port": proxyPort,
              "network.proxy.socks": proxyIP,
              "network.proxy.socks_port": proxyPort,
              "network.proxy.socks_remote_dns": True,
              "network.proxy.ftp": proxyIP,
              "network.proxy.ftp_port": proxyPort
              }
browser = Browser('firefox', profile_preferences=proxy_settings)
browser.visit("http://www.icanhazip.com")
```

Didn't work. Just get these errors

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35-32\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\common\service.py", line 74, in start
    stdout=self.log_file, stderr=self.log_file)
  File "C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35-32\lib\subprocess.py", line 947, in **init**
    restore_signals, start_new_session)
  File "C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35-32\lib\subprocess.py", line 1224, in _execute_child
    startupinfo)
FileNotFoundError: [WinError 2] The system cannot find the file specified

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/User/PycharmProjects/LittleBot/Main.py", line 15, in 
    browser = Browser('firefox', profile_preferences=proxy_settings)
  File "C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35-32\lib\site-packages\splinter\browser.py", line 63, in Browser
    return driver(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35-32\lib\site-packages\splinter\driver\webdriver\firefox.py", line 48, in **init**
    timeout=timeout)
  File "C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35-32\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\firefox\webdriver.py", line 140, in **init**
    self.service.start()
  File "C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35-32\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\common\service.py", line 81, in start
    os.path.basename(self.path), self.start_error_message)
selenium.common.exceptions.WebDriverException: Message: 'geckodriver' executable needs to be in PATH.

Exception ignored in: >
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35-32\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\common\service.py", line 173, in **del**
    self.stop()
  File "C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35-32\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\common\service.py", line 145, in stop
    if self.process is None:
AttributeError: 'Service' object has no attribute 'process'

Process finished with exit code 1

I installed all the libraries requested on the webpage, and even did that --upgrade selenium thing in hopes of getting rid of the errors.
Is there any way to solve this? 
So far all I know is that the program runs just fine until the 'browser = Browser('firefox', profile_preferences=proxy_settings)' occurs. Also the Tor browser is open, so no problems there.
Been searching for an hour and a half for a solution to this, and I've tried everything that relates to this subject.

Answer (score 0):

Fixed it

```
pip install selenium==2.53.6
```

Selenium wants to introduce some gecko thing and that's messing with everything. 
Hope this is of use to other people.

Comment: "some gecko thing" is geckodriver, and it is now a requirement in selenium 3.x to drive Firefox... similar to how you need chromedriver to drive Chrome.

Answer (score -1):

To use selenium 3.x with Firefox, you must install geckodriver.
The official site for releases is here: https://github.com/mozilla/geckodriver/releases

from the selenium python docs:

> "Selenium requires a driver to interface with the chosen browser.
>   Firefox, for example, requires geckodriver, which needs to be
>   installed before the below examples can be run. Make sure it’s in your
>   PATH, e. g., place it in /usr/bin or /usr/local/bin.
>
> Failure to observe this step will give you an error
>   selenium.common.exceptions.WebDriverException: Message: ‘geckodriver’
>   executable needs to be in PATH."

Comment: This doesn't answer the question and just points to where the error is raised and not even getting till Tor.

Answer (score -2):

If you are using latest selenium and latest Firefox
1. Download latest geckodriver
2. Open tor browser, hide it.
3. run code:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.firefox.firefox_binary import FirefoxBinary
from selenium.webdriver.firefoc.firefox_profile import FirefoxProfile

binary = FirefoxBinary('C:/Program Files(x86)/Mozilla Firefox/firefox.exe')
profile = webdriver.FirefoxProfile()

profile.set_preference('network.proxy.type', 1)
profile.set_preference('network.proxy.socks', '127.0.0.1')
profile.set_preference('network.proxy.socks_port', 9150)

driver = webdriver.Firefox(firefox_binary = binary, firefox_profile = profile, executable_path='path/to/geckodriver.exe')
driver.get('https://check.torproject.org')
```

Comment: tor is a browser, he is trying to use tor instead of firefox, not to use firefox to browse to the tor site. even tho tor and firefox are built from same parent